# Python 2 -> 3 Django migration causes field parameter type change

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

We are transitioning a Django project from Django 1.8 -> 2.1 and Python 2.7 -> 3.6.

In the old project version, there are Django models that looked like this, for example:

```
# models.py

from django.db import models

class RowStatusModel(models.Model):
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, db_column='is_active')
    # ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Notice that `from __future__ import unicode_literals` is *not* used in this module.  That means that `db_column` is a Python 2 `str`, corresponding to `bytes` in Python 3.  The initial migration, 0001_initial.py, looks like this:

```
# 0001_initial.py

operations = [
    # ...
    ('row_ef', models.BooleanField(default=True, db_column=b'is_active')
    # ...
]
```

Notice the byte-literal `b'is_active`, which I suppose was done by Django in the interest of being more explicit, but am not sure.

Now after transitioning most of the codebase with 2to3 and running `makemigrations`, Python 3 treats a string literal as what would be the unicode type in Python 2, and consequently generates a migration where the `db_column` is a string literal, for every single model that inherits from `RowStatusModel`:

```
# migrations/0023_auto_20180827_1955.py 
migrations.AlterField(
    # ...
    field=models.BooleanField(default=True, db_column='is_active')
), # ...
```

**What effect, if any**, will this have on the database side when `./manage.py migrate` is ran?  Is the "change" purely on the Python side, or what side effects may be created?

---

Database engine is `django.db.backends.postgresql`.

---

I'm aware that we can just clone the RDS instance and revert back to that if `migrate` causes immediate problems, but I am more concerned about more subtle issues being introduced that would not be caught until much later on.

Comment: As noted in the last comment on that ticket, you can just edit the existing migrations to remove the `b` prefixes on strings. The newly generated migration will not have any effect if you choose to generate it.

Comment: @BradSolomon That's what we did when migrating to Python3 (altering existing migrations). No new migrations were generated and we had no issues (backends usually postgres).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I came across a [Django ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23226) after asking this question, where the recommendation from a Django developer is to edit any legacy migrations files (such as 0001_initial) that contain (Python 3) bytes literals, removing the `b` and making them string-literals in Python 3.

> Editing migrations to fix this issue is safe.

From there you should presumably be able to delete the migrations modules that were made with `python3 ./manage.py makemigrations`, and redo that command, which should no longer take issue with the type of that argument.

I used the following to do a mass-find-and-replace of all instances of `'db_column=b'` with `'db_column='`.  Granted, you should absolutely check `git diff` before making that commit.

```
grep -nrl "db_column=b" apps | xargs sed -i "s/db_column=b/db_column=/g"
```

Comment: You can check the database effect of a migration with `sqlmigrate` command. This migrations will most probably have no effect on db. Django generates migrations even if the `choices` parameter for a field changes, without any db effect. And there are other cases for 'no-sql' migrations.

Comment: In a more complicated situation, where editing all the existing migrations would be too time-consuming, it's worth considering to simply generate this migrations without effect just to make django happy, and continue as usual (commit, migrate,..).